# Filling a 13-by-13 square

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Is it possible to arrange the integers $1,2,3,\ldots,169$ in a $13\times13$ square, so that in every $2\times2$ square the sum of the four numbers is divisible by $170$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> yes [image]Basically we just have ordered pairs of 170 alternating with high-low left/right. The pattern to figure out which pairs go where is very simple as well: We start with the square 1 169, 168 2. If we take 2 steps to the right, we do -13 if the original was bigger then 85, and +13 if it was smaller. If we take 2 steps down, we do -2 if the original was bigger then 85, and +2 if it was smaller. This way the whole 13x13 square can be filled as in the image. The numbers below are all possible sums and they are (ofcourse) all 340.

Comment: Great, the pattern formed is intriguing...